# Get the HTML that makes up an element in Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the HTML that makes up an element using Jquery or Javascript?
For example if I have an element that looks like

```
<div id="theDivIWant" class="aClassName" style="somestyle: "here"></div>
```

I can grab a reference to it using

var x = document.getElementById("theDivIWant")
or $("#theDivIWant")

but how can I actually retrieve the string?

```
"<div id="theDivIWant" class="aClassName" style="somestyle: "here"></div>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement [outerHTML](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/) with jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

the `outerHTML` property will give you what you want in IE; in webkit and firefox, you can get the innerHTML of the parent and filter it:

```
var whatYouWantPlusItsSiblings = $('#target').closest().html();
```

From there, you can strip the content you don't need.  Alternatively, if you have control over the markup, you can surround your target with another well-known element and get that parent's innerHTML.

Comment: May be worth noting that outerHTML is part of HTML5 now, and is also supported in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 2):

if it is the only child of its parent, this should work:

```
$('#theDivIWant').parent().html();
```

If it is not the only child, you may be able to combine the above code with some regex to extract only it from the results.